# React Hook Form dirtyFields returns incomplete/ missing field that should be dirty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

One field in my form `endTimeMins` seems to be not registering to formState. I have four fields all of them have no problem being dirty, I can read them as dirty but not the `endTimeMins` field.Additional information, I am using MUI v4 for my input components.

I created the input fields in a reusable way. Overall it renders 4 fields.

**Here is my startTimeHour/endTimeHour first.**

```
   <Controller
      name={`${timeType}Hour`}
      control={control}
      rules={{ required: true, validate: () => _isEndGreaterThanStart() || errorMsgs.endNotGreater }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value, name, onInputChange } }) => (
        <Controls.SingleAutoComplete
          name={`${timeType}Hour`}
          disableClearable
          freeSolo
          value={value.toString()}
          inputValue={value}
          className={classes.autoCompleteInput}
          error={!!errors[name]?.message}
          options={HOURS_OPTIONS.map((option) => option.value)}
          onChange={(e, newValue) => {
            onChange(newValue);
            _handleStartEndRelation(name, newValue);
          }}
          onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
            onChange(handleTimeInputs(newValue, 12).toString()); //handle unwanted inputs
            _handleStartEndRelation(name, newValue);
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

And here is for my startTimeMins/**endTimeMins**

```
<Controller
      name={`${timeType}Mins`}
      control={control}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value, name, onBlur } }) => (
        <Controls.SingleAutoComplete
          name={`${timeType}Mins`}
          options={MINS_OPTIONS.map((option) => option.value)}
          getOptionDisabled={(option) => option === MINS_OPTIONS[4].value}
          disableClearable
          className={classes.autoCompleteInput}
          freeSolo
          error={!!errors.endTimeHour?.message && name === 'endTimeMins'}
          value={value.toString()}
          inputValue={value}
          onChange={(e, newValue) => {
            onChange(newValue);
            trigger('endTimeHour');
          }}
          onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
            onChange(handleTimeInputs(newValue, 59, true).toString()); 
            _handleStartEndRelation(name, handleTimeInputs(newValue, 59, true).toString());
            
          }}
          onBlur={() => {  
            if (value.length === 1) {
              onChange(`0${value}`);
              _handleStartEndRelation(name, `0${value}`);
             
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Let me also show my function that handles relation between my inputs. This is just basically increment endTime basing on startTime.

```
  const _handleStartEndRelation = (name, value) => {
    if (name === 'startTimeHour' && value !== '0') {
      if (value === '12') {
        setValue('endTimeHour', '1');
      } else if (value === '') {
        setValue('endTimeHour', '');
      } else {
        setValue('endTimeHour', +value + 1);
      }
    }

    if (name === 'startTimeMins') {
      setValue('endTimeMins', value);
    }

    trigger('endTimeHour');
  };
```

With all that I have no problem getting or setting the values for the fields. Is just the isDirty state for my field endTime is having undefined when I check `console.log(_getFieldState('endTimeMins').isDirty);`and it is missing from the dirtyFields when I check it using `console.log(dirtyFields);`

I made sure I set it in defaultValues as well.

```
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    _getFieldState,
    trigger,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { isDirty, dirtyFields, isValid, errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      OFIdate: new Date(),
      startTimeHour: '',
      endTimeHour: '',
      startTimeMins: '',
      endTimeMins: ''
    },
    mode: 'onChange'
  });
```

What could I be missing here? I compare my code fields to each other and it's not that different for me. So why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
setValue('name', 'value', { shouldDirty: true })
```

I guess when I need to set field values with `setValue()`, I also have to manually set if they are dirty.

Comment: Setting shouldDirty to true actually computes if your input is dirty or not against your defaultValues.