# dirty fields (react-hook-form) Doesn't work on controller with an object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, controller, react-hook-form

This is my 'Controller':

```
return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={rName}
      rules={{ required: "وارد کردن این فیلد اجباری است" }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <DatePicker
          value={value}
          calendar={persian}
          locale={persian_fa}
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          onOpenPickNewDate={false}
          calendarPosition="bottom-right"
          {...datePickerProps}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onChange(e);
            datePickerProps.onChange && datePickerProps.onChange(e);
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
```

and this is the default value I gave it:

```
import { DateObject, toDateObject } from "react-multi-date-picker";
toDateObject(new Date(defaultValues.my_input_8 || ""))
```

But whenever I change the date in the browser, it doesn't trigger any change in this specific input. dirtyFields and touchedFields do not include this input.

I tried to set the value of the controller with e.toString but I think it's not ideal because some features became unavailable for example some methods like value.toJSON(), value.format(), value.convert() and ... It's better if it can be done with object as value of the controller.

Comment: this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221547/react-hook-form-dirtyfields-returns-incomplete-missing-field-that-should-be-dir